# In Camel port number get removed on Redirection Url

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, openshift

For redirection I am using following code

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
exchange.getIn().setHeader("Location", "http://10.5.5.111:8081/Test");
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, "307");
```

redirection working in local but after deployment on open shift after redirection I am able to see port number gets removed from browser and http gets replace with https.
like

original url : http://10.5.5.111:8081/Test

after redirection : https://10.5.5.111/Test   --> here port gets removed and http replaced with https

Comment: Have you checked the raw-response received from your Camel service that the HTTP location header contains the mentioned HTTPS URI or did you just determine the problem by looking at your browser and that it presents the HTTPS URI after the response was received? Modern browsers may attempt to switch to HTTPS if the server supports it and this might be the causing issue here, but just a random speculation to be fair

Comment: I checked response port and http in Location header it's getting changed in redirection as mentioned above